# Translate createHmac from crypto to crypto-js with Buffers

Tags: javascript, cryptography, hmac, one-time-password, totp

I am trying to translate a given Code using crypto to a version using crypto-js without luck so far.

I am not even able to get the same hash values.
The final goal is to generate TOTP tokens and I need to do it with crypto-js, because I want to generate them in a webbrowser.

The critical part is "Step 1: Generate an HMAC-SHA-1 value", I am not able to get a identical result as in const hmacResult = hmac.digest(); in crypto-js...

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cryptojs = require('crypto-js');
const base32 = require('hi-base32');

function generateHOTP(secret, counter) {
   const decodedSecret = base32.decode.asBytes(secret);
   const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
   for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      buffer[7 - i] = counter & 0xff;
      counter = counter >> 8;
   }

   // Step 1: Generate an HMAC-SHA-1 value
   let hmacjs = cryptojs.algo.HMAC.create(cryptojs.algo.SHA1, cryptojs.enc.Utf8.stringify(decodedSecret) );
   hmacjs.update(buffer);
   console.log(hmacjs.finalize().toString());
   
   const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', Buffer.from(decodedSecret)); 
   hmac.update(buffer);
   const hmacResult = hmac.digest();
   console.log(hmacResult.toString('hex'));
   
   // Step 2: Generate a 4-byte string (Dynamic Truncation)
   const code = dynamicTruncationFn(hmacResult);

   // Step 3: Compute an HOTP value
   return code % 10 ** 6;
}

function dynamicTruncationFn(hmacValue) {
   const offset = hmacValue[hmacValue.length - 1] & 0xf;

   return (
      ((hmacValue[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
      ((hmacValue[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) |
      ((hmacValue[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) |
      (hmacValue[offset + 3] & 0xff)
   );
}

function generateTOTP(secret, window = 0) {
   const counter = Math.floor(Date.now() / 30000);
   return generateHOTP(secret, counter + window);
}

console.log(generateTOTP('GEZDGNBVGY3TQOJQGEZDG', 0));
```

I tried diverse variation and consulted the documentations, but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptoJS uses the `WordArray` data type internally, i.e. you have to convert `decodedSecret` (JavaScript array) and `buffer` (NodeJS buffer) into a `WordArray` and the resulting HMAC as `WordArray` into a NodeJS buffer.

There are several approaches to this. One possibility is the conversion via latin1:

```js
// Step 1: Generate an HMAC-SHA-1 value
let decodedSecretWA = cryptojs.enc.Latin1.parse(Buffer.from(decodedSecret).toString('latin1')); // JS array -> WordArray 
let bufferWA = cryptojs.enc.Latin1.parse(buffer.toString('latin1'));                            // NodeJS Buffer -> WordArray
let hmacjsWA = cryptojs.algo.HMAC.create(cryptojs.algo.SHA1, decodedSecretWA);
hmacjsWA.update(bufferWA);
let hmacResultjsWA = hmacjsWA.finalize();
const hmacResultjs = Buffer.from(hmacResultjsWA.toString(cryptojs.enc.Latin1), 'latin1'); // WordArray -> NodeJS Buffer
console.log(hmacResultjs);
```

Another approach is to convert *directly* to a `WordArray` with `cryptojs.lib.WordArray.create()`, which can handle JavaScript arrays (via typed arrays) and NodeJS buffers. There is no CryptoJS support for the reverse direction, but e.g. `CryptJsWordArrayToUint8Array()` from [here](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/274#issuecomment-600039187) can be applied:

```js
// Step 1: Generate an HMAC-SHA-1 value
let decodedSecretWA = cryptojs.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array(decodedSecret)); // JS array -> WordArray 
let bufferWA = cryptojs.lib.WordArray.create(buffer);                               // NodeJS Buffer -> WordArray
let hmacjsWA = cryptojs.algo.HMAC.create(cryptojs.algo.SHA1, decodedSecretWA);
hmacjsWA.update(bufferWA);
let hmacResultjsWA = hmacjsWA.finalize();
const hmacResultjs = Buffer.from(CryptJsWordArrayToUint8Array(hmacResultjsWA)); // WordArray -> NodeJS Buffer
console.log(hmacResultjs);
```